# jQuery selecting numerous divs with the same class outside of the currently clicked div

Tags: jquery, html

I have a div that contains a dynamic number of specific children that I need to change from hide to show. Its really hard to explain but the code gives a clear picture.

```
<div class="item_content_container">
    <div class="content_container">
        <div class="item">ITEM A</div>
        <div class="item">ITEM B</div>
        <div class="item">ITEM C</div>
    </div>
    <div class="content_container">
        <div class="item">ITEM A</div>
        <div class="item">ITEM B</div>
        <div class="item">ITEM C</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="item_options_container">
    <div class="item_click">CLICK</div>
</div>
```

The code can continue to repeat itself so I only want to select the "item" classes before the "item_click" div.

here is the jQuery:

```
$(".item_click").live('click', function () {
    $(this).parent().siblings(".item_content_container").find(".item").show();
});
```

Comment: I am trying to show() all of the "item" classes that are in the "item_content_container" div right before the "item_click" div.

Comment: just replace `siblings` with `prev` then ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/oyuwiw/1/edit)**</kbd>

```
$(".item_options_container").on('click', '.item_click', function () {
    $(this).closest('.item_options_container')
           .prev('.item_content_container')
           .find('.item')
           .show();      
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/on/ <sup>(`.live()` method is deprecated)</sup>
http://api.jquery.com/closest/ (or also `.parent()` in your case)
http://api.jquery.com/prev/
http://api.jquery.com/find/

Comment: Thanks man. I tried to use .on though and it wont work. What version do i need to upgrade to for .on to work?

Comment: If it's delegated, you need another syntax when using on() !